# Redirect 301 not working

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I try to a redirect all pages and folder from my old domain  from www.mydomeain.com/v2 to www.mydomeain.com

eg 
from www.mydomain.com/v2/folder/page.php to www.mydomain.com/page1.php
I am try

```
Redirect 301 /folder/page.php http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php
```

but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect *from* `www.mydomain.com/v2/folder/page.php`, then you're missing the `v2`, assuming that the directive is in your site's document root:

```
Redirect 301 /v2/folder/page.php http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php
```